# I don't know my passphrase

Tags: installation, security

I have just installed Ubuntu and I am not sure what my password is. I don't really know that much about computers.

Answer (score 2):

Do this, boot into recovery-mode. to do that, press shift at the purple screen. Then a menu should come up and from there select recovery-mode. Now a ton of text will apear, but then another menu will apear. From there select root command line or something like that. Then I think you can just type:

```
passwd <username>
```

and then type in your new password, when you're done, type

```
reboot
```

and boot normally.

If you run into an "Authentication token manipulation" error, then you first need to type:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then do the `passwd` command.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on the Ubuntu icon
2. Type in **UXTerm** & select
3. Type **passwd** into the box
4. Now enter a new password & press enter
5. Re-enter your new password

You have now changed your password.

Comment: No, You cant if you dont know the existing password.

Comment: Yes you can do it the way I mentioned, hence you not having to know the original password.

Comment: Password *does* need current password. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJNB85mxtCI

Comment: I wouldn't be giving out wrong information, I've used this way myself several times.

Comment: passwd only requires the current password, if you are not root (or if you are root and want to change the root password). Root can change the password of any ordinary user without knowing the current one.

Comment: Try my method, you won't screw your system up, I can assure you.